# what is the difference here in this use of JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the difference in the following    between the result of `p` and `q` and why would you do either way, which is best?

```
        var my = [
                {"a":"sdsds"},
                {"b":"sdsds"},
                {"c":"sdsds"},
                {"d":"sdsds"},
                {"e":"sdsds"}
        ];






        var p = JSON.stringify({ "myText": my };);
        var q = { "myText": JSON.stringify(my) };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p` is a string containing:

```
'{"myText":[{"a":"sdsds"},{"b":"sdsds"},{"c":"sdsds"},{"d":"sdsds"},{"e":"sdsds"}]}'
```

`q` is an object:

```
{
    myText: '[{"a":"sdsds"},{"b":"sdsds"},{"c":"sdsds"},{"d":"sdsds"},{"e":"sdsds"}]'
}
```

They're not the same thing, so I can't tell you which is best. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: thank you - for an ajax post - so I guess the way you have explained it then q is the way to go.

Comment: @Hello-World: Possibly. Did you actually want to send the array as part of the JSON? If so, `var q = { myText: my };` would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is a string that looks like `"{ \"mytext\": ... }"`.

`q` is an object with a property called `mytext`.

Comment: that would explain my my code behind isnt picking up "myText" when I pass it p but it works with q

Answer (score 3):

One creates a JSON text consisting of an object with the property 'myText' with the value being the data that 'my' contains (i.e. an array of objects each of which has one property/string pair).

The other creates an object consisting of a property 'myText' with the value being a string containing a JSON text built from the data in 'my'.

> why would you do either way

The former is generally the approach taken when creating JSON.

That latter might be useful if you planned to pass the object to something like jQuery's `data` property in an `.ajax()` call.

> which is best

Neither. They simply different. "Best" is whatever works for what you are going to do with the variables.